# Windows 10 freezes at "Preparing Automatic Repair" on a MacBookPro (Bootcamp'ed)

Tags: boot, boot-camp, windows-10-preview

Well, at first I should've stopped the auto updates or either took an image of the system at least to be on the safer side. I'm not sure what went or may be an update, but now the boot screen just stopped at "Preparing Automatic Repair" and that's it.

I've tried uninstalling an update once using the advance troubleshoot menu and  it worked. But now again, it had all gone wrong. Even when I try to uninstall the updates, it fails.

Any idea on how to get this fixed?